# How thick should kitchen cabinet shelves be?

Tags: cabinets, custom-cabinetry

We recently had a professional build our kitchen cabinets, and noticed after we paid them in full that the shelves inside the upper cabinets were only 5/8" thick.  We applied pressure to the middle back area of the shelves and they flexed downward.  Shouldn't shelves be 3/4" thick for rigidity and strength?

Comment: Think it would depend on the selves length.  Think the only selves I have that are 3/4, is a small bookcase with over 5 or 6 feet between supports.  Most of the others are 1/2 or 5/8 inch thick.

Comment: The longest shelf span is 30" .  They are adjustable shelves with no support underneath;  concerned the adjustable pins might pop out when too much weight is on them, not to mention that they dip in the middle when pressure is applied.

Comment: They should last, mine have lasted over 30 years, and sounds like standard cabinet construction.  Will depend on the quality of the shelves themselves and the amount of weight on them.

Comment: It depends on the material, and for that, ask the cabinetmaker. If it is particle board with a covering of melamine or faux wood grain it will sag on its own over time. If it is a solid wood shelf, depending on the specie of wood, it will bow with weight applied, and may stay that way over time. If it is a strong wood like oak or fir, it will do what you need. It may bow under a big load, but will return once the load is removed.

Comment: What did your contract with the builder specify?

Comment: He never specified shelf thickness beforehand.  We are new at this so didn't even know to raise the issue.  In all of our homes we've had 3/4" thick shelves, so thought it was standard.  There is no particleboard;  the shelves are plywood ~ we think maple.   Most of what I've read online says they should be 3/4" thick.

Comment: How much "pressure to the middle back area"? Anything will bend if you push it hard enough.

Comment: _"...had a professional build our kitchen cabinets..."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: 5/8" plywood shelves spanning 30" are fine. They aren't going to fall.

5/8" shelves might seem a little slim, especially when you've been primed to think that 3/4" are better, but under normal loads, these should be fine. (Assuming plywood -- particle core is a different matter, and you can probably see what the actual core is by looking at the back of the shelf.)

They aren't going to flex themselves off the shelf pins and cascade down.

If you end up storing your collection of osmium or tungsten up there, then the shelf might sag a little and somebody will install a 1x2 of hardwood, oriented vertically, at the back of the shelf and that problem will go away.

edit: just to add mention of a very useful tool: the [Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) that says a 30" wide, 12" deep, 5/8" ply shelf with 30# per foot uniformly distributed will sag .02" (<2mm) or less.

Comment: If the sag becomes permanent and noticeable, you might want to turn the shelf over. That will remove the sag.